# Best way to make a "Data Bag" that serializes with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I've been having a hard time figuring out what is the best method to create a "Data Bag" class that can also serialize its data using Protobuf-Net's lightweight serialization, for which I create my own TypeModel. I'm trying to avoid storing the data as Objects. Bascially, something that can do:

```
DataBag bag = new DataBag();

bag.Add<T>("dataName", value);
bag.Get<T>("dataName");
```

My solution was to create a wrapper class that has a member of each of my serializable types, and then use two sorting dictionaries whose keys are my types, and provide the correct action to set and get the value, like so:

```
public class Datum
{
    public int AsInt;
    public string AsString;
    public bool AsBool;
    public int[] AsIntArray;
    public string[] AsStringArray;
    public bool[] AsBoolArray;
}
```

The bag class builds two static sorting dictionaries and the dictionary that will be serialized like so:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Action<Object, Datum>> ValueSet { get; set; }
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<Datum, Object>> ValueGet { get; set; }

private Dictionary<string, Datum> Data { get; set; }

....

ValueSet.Add(typeof(int), (value, datum) => datum.AsInt = (int)value);
ValueGet.Add(typeof(int), (datum) => datum.AsInt);
```

Then on the methods themselves I do:

```
public void Add<T>(string name, Object value)
{
    Datum datum = new Datum();
    ValueSet[typeof(T)](value, datum);
    Data.Add(name, datum);
}

public T Get<T>(string name)
{
    return (T)ValueGet[typeof(T)](Data[name]);
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that as the amount of serializable objects increases, I have to keep maintaining the class and add new entries on the sorting dictionaries along with more members on the Datum wrapper. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid storing the data in an object field? Please list out the disadvantages. Then describe how your current solution is superior.

Comment: The problem I'm having with storing data in an object is the serialization with Protobuf-Net, the only way I've found to serialize an Object is through the DynamicType attribute, but it doesn't permit the object to be a primitive type.

Comment: Could a generic wrapper class help?

Comment: I managed to make it work using a generic wrapper class, however what would be the best way to have only one data dictionary that accepts all the different generic Datum<T> objects? The only thing I could think of was to make a base class from which Datum<T> derives and make the Dictionary<string, BaseDatum>, however in protobuf I have to specify through attributes all the derived classes so I'd still have to add a new attribute and new type on the model for each new serializable class. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net isn't **designed** to store data bags; it is designed to work with known contracts, lot least because the protobuf format is very light on metadata.

You *could* perhaps use the extension data API, but the problem there is that data doesn't have *names* (because the protobuf format never stores names) - it has *field numbers*. If you can use *numbers*, support for storing, retrieving and round-tripping ad-hoc data is built in.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand this is over-extending the design of Protobuf-Net. In hindsight, it was a mistake on my part to simply chose the fastest serializer I could find without first thinking through if it fit for what I needed it. Ultimately, I did manage to make it work with generic wrappers and runtime models. Thanks though!